# Posting result in mysql WHERE statement from form ($_GET) when no selection is made by a user

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, get

Sorry if this has been asked before, I searched but couldn't find a suitable answer. There is probably a simple answer for this, but I'm stumped and hoping someone can provide a quick answer. I've got a form on my site where users can *filter* the data multiple ways. One *filtering* option in the the form is 'intensity' (low, medium, high). I'm using $_GET variables to post in the mysql WHERE statement. It works fine when an intensity option is chosen, but when the user does not choose an option I get no results output. What can I use as a value in the form that will end up outputting all intensities in the WHERE statement.

Below are snippets of the code...

```
<form action="workouts.php" method="GET" style="margin-top:5px">
<small>intensity</small>
<select id="intensity" name="intensity"> 
      <option value="" selected="selected"></option> 
      <option value="low">Low</option> 
      <option value="medium">Medium</option> 
      <option value="high">High</option> 
      <option value="auto">Auto</option> 
 </select>
<small> <input type="submit" value="go" style="font-size:12px"/></small>
</form>

<?php  $intensity = $_GET['intensity']; ?>
```

This is the WHERE statement I'm calling $intensity in...

SELECT * FROM data WHERE `complete` = '1' and `intensity` = '$intensity' ORDER by `date` DESC

Comment: Build your query dynamically. Don't include the `instensity` condition if no value is supplied.

Comment: Side note: in your question you say sorting, but what you're describing is filtering.

Comment: Correct, filtering by intensity. How do I go about excluding the intensity condition from the where statement when no value is supplied. There will be additional filters included as well, so additional adds to the where statement etc.. Sorry if there is an obvious solution, again...this is new to me, so it seems like there would just be a value I could put in that accounts for all intensities, but maybe I'm wrong? Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: There is no such wildcard you could use (at least to the extent of my knowledge). Whenever I have to dynamically create a `WHERE` condition, I usually build an array of options with column name as key and the filter value as the value under that key. That way I can concatenate the conditions to the query with a simple `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normally solved by using an or in your query:

```
SELECT * FROM data 
WHERE complete = '1' 
AND ('' = '$intensity' OR intensity = '$intensity') 
ORDER by date DESC
```

So if intensity is empty the first will match '' = '' and all rows will match.
If intensity is 'low' the first will not match but the second part will match on all rows with intensity set to low.

Comment: Thanks! That looks like it worked perfectly!